# How to use a class in an if statement

Tags: c#

I'm trying to get my if statement to check if a file contains the letter 
"M", "F" or "U"

If it contains any other letter or no letter then it should return false.

I'm getting the error:

> "CS1955  C# Non-invocable member "SplitClass.Patient.Gender" cannot be used like a method."

How can I fix this so that I can use my GenderOptions class in the if statement?

```
 public class Patient
    {
        public int NHSNumber { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string GivenName { get; set; }
        public string Surname { get; set; }
        public GenderOptions Gender { get; set; }

    }

    public enum GenderOptions
    {
        M,
        F,
        U
    };

    public enum TitleOptions
    {
        Mr,
        Master,
        Miss,
        Mrs,
        Ms,
        Mx

    };



    public bool Validation(Patient patient)
    {
        if (patient.NHSNumber > 10) return false;
        if (patient.NHSNumber < 10) return false;
        if (patient.DateOfBirth.Year > DateTime.Today.Year) return false;
        if (patient.DateOfBirth.Year < 1900) return false;
        if (patient.Gender != ("M","F","U")) return false;
    }
```

I plan to do the same for the TitleOptions too, I am just confused as how I can use the Gender class in the if statement properly.

> //Pseudocode
>   If (filename) does not contain "M", "F", or "U"
>
> Then Console.WriteLine ("Does not contain valid gender");

Comment: You say checking a filename contains the letters m,f or u but in your code you're comparing gender options which is an enum ?

Comment: @PeterB I'm sure this is a duplicate, but not of that - he is trying to validate an Enum, not a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Enum.IsDefined

```
if (!Enum.IsDefined(typeof(GenderOptions), patient.Gender)){
    return false;
}
```

You could also use Enum.TryParse or something